# Spring-Web Very High Vulnerability in 5.x.x Version

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

We are using spring-web in one of our projects which uses Java 8 and Veracode has reported a v high flaw in spring-web framework.
I know updated 6.x.x has been released and it's vulnerability free but in order to update to spirng 6 Java needs to be updated considering our project is very old and on path of EOL by this Sept upgrading it to Java 17 is somewhat not a feasible option.
Are we expecting any release for 5.x.x version with this vulnerability fixed?

Comment: Without knowing which 5.x version this is impossible to know, it would also be interesting to know **which vulnerability** as it might have been fixed already in some other version or dependent library upgrade.

Comment: Spring-web version 5.3.25 vulerability CVE-2016-1000027 this has been fixed in 6.x.x release but as mentioned above we cant update to 6.x.x version

Comment: It isn't an issue if you don't use the classes. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24434#issuecomment-744519525 (you probably aren't using those as those are about HTTP Invoker and friends thus you aren't vulnerable). It is "fixed" in 6.x because that removed those classes. Those security check are pretty dumb as they can only check the classes on the classpath not which ones you are actually using.

Comment: [The most eloquent comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24434#issuecomment-581524820): "Doing this would be a breaking change and we would need to create a new artifact for that. This is typically the type of change we apply for major releases." - remediating vulnerability is a breaking change.

Answer (score 1):

The problem highlighted by this CVE is that deserialization of Java serialized objects from an untrusted source is dangerous.

However, flagging all versions of Spring-Web 5.x.x as being vulnerable is misleading.  Sure, the Spring-Web codebase has code that allows that to happen.  But so do all versions of Java ... until they deprecate and remove Java object serialization entirely.  (That is described as a "long term goal", but I doubt that will happen any time soon.)

The correct way to deal with this is not to "upgrade" ... but to audit your code carefully to look for places where you are using Java object deserialization.  Then you check each place to see if you are (potentially) getting the data from an untrusted source, or a source that *could* be compromised thereby rendering it risky.

- If you are not using Java object serialization you are fine.
- If you are not getting the serialized data from an untrusted (or risky) source you are (probably) fine ... modulo the accuracy of your assumptions and your analysis.
- Otherwise you need to change your application to stop *using* Java object serialization / deserialization in a *risky* way.  Do it another way; e.g. use JSON and a JSON binding technology.

---

Note that upgrading to Spring-Web 6 or higher doesn't actually solve the problem anyway.  Sure they removed the "vulnerable" classes, but the "ability" to use Java serialization unsafely exists in Java.  Spring-Web cannot prevent it.

---

For more background, I recommend that you read [issue 24434](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24434) on the Spring issue tracker.

In particular, read [this comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24434#issuecomment-744519525) from one of the developers which explains their stance on the issue.